# How to add a list into list with same count

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a 2 different dataset list in C#.

list1 have property  price1,price2,price3. both are different classes collection
list2  have property price4,price5,price6.

```
var list1 = (from m in dbcontext.List1details)ToList();                
var list2 = (from s in  List2details).ToList();

In list1   I have **147 values** and list 2 have 147 values.
```

How to add list 1 and list2 with same count.

when i add it in the another list , the count is 147+147 =>294.

i need same count with single list.

Here is a sample Program , but it will throw error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1= List1.GetList1();
            var list2 = List2.GetList12();


           // List3 m = new List3();
            //m.list = list1;
            //m.list2 = list2;

        List <List3> m = new List<List3> ();
        m.Add(list1);


// here this line is wrong,i need to add and take list1 of values add with list2 of values.
            foreach(var x in m)
            {
                // here i have to add list1 values and list2 values 
               var x = list1.LocationValues1 + list2.LocationValues4;

            Console.WriteLine(x);


        }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }

    public class List1 {
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public decimal LocationValues1 { get; set; }
        public decimal LocationValues2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CreatedDate { get; set; }



        public static List<List1> GetList1()
        {
            var list1 = new List<List1>
                {
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=199.23M,LocationValues2=22.90M },
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=199.23M,LocationValues2=22.90M },
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=199.23M,LocationValues2=22.90M },
                    new List1 {LocationName="Africa",LocationValues1=199.23M,LocationValues2=22.90M },
                };

            return list1;
        }
    }


    public class List2
    {
        public string ContinentName { get; set; }
        public decimal LocationValues4 { get; set; }
        public decimal LocationValues5 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CreatedDate { get; set; }



        public static List<List2> GetList12()
        {
            var list2 = new List<List2>
                {
                    new List2{ ContinentName="Asia",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                    new List2 { ContinentName ="Africa",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                    new List2 { ContinentName ="Australia",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                    new List2 { ContinentName ="Pakistan",LocationValues4=199.23M,LocationValues5=22.90M },
                };

            return list2;
        }
    }


    public class List3
    {
        public List< List1 > list{ get;set;}
        public List<List2> list2 { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: You have apples and pears and you want to make applepear-sauce? Is there a common class with all those properties or what you want to select?

Comment: Could you provide *some examples* of the desired results? Suppose we have `[10.0, 20.0]` as `list1` and `[18.0, 27.0]` as `list2`; what are  desired `list` values then?

Comment: What's with all the tags? I'm sure you're not using all those versions at once.

Comment: And why did you stop at c#-4.0 ?

Comment: Your code is full of errors, it doesn't even compile. Just as an example: `m.Add(list1);` doesn't work, because `list1` is not of the type `List3` and `list1.LocationValues1` can't work, because `list1` does not contain the property `LocationValues1`, since `list1` is a `List<List1>` and not an object of the class `List1`. Please correct the mistakes, so we can test your code and describe your needs more in detail. Furthermore your whole structure of dozen of nested Lists is quite messy, it is impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve, please specify.

Comment: @ L. Guthardt i will add the program with clear example after some time, yes now you will get a compile error,i agree. my question is simple i have list 1 with different dataset - count is 147 and list2 have different dataset 2 , when i add it in new list , its count is 294 ,  i dont want list  294 and i need 147 as count and  need to do a calculation in combined list 147 as count add the list 1 property1 + list2property2.

Comment: Do you still need a help with this task?

Comment: @Maciej Pulikowski  No thanks  for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List3 should have elements you want to, not a lists. Ex.

```
public class List3
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public decimal LocationValues14 { get; set; }
    public decimal LocationValues25 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now using lenght of the list 1 or 2(they are same) and choosing variables of lists elements. Build a new list by creating new objects and adding them to list3.

```
for(var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    List3 newElementList3 = new List3(){
        CreatedDate = list1[i].CreatedDate,
        LocationName = list1[i].LocationName,
        LocationValues14 = list1[i].LocationValues1 + list2[i].LocationValues4,
        LocationValues25 = list1[i].LocationValues2 + list2[i].LocationValues5,
    };

    list3.Add(newElementList3);
}
```

Hope it's that problem you had in mind :P

please don't give a name for items like "list1".

Cheers